# Is there a common way of shortening German adjectives?

Tags: contractions

Speaking of poetry or ease of speech, is there a common way of shortening adjectives? An example of my question using a noun instead of an adjective would be saying "mei-" perhaps, instead of "meine," to not confuse with "mein?" But my question relates to adjectives.

Comment: But mein is not an adjective. Do you mean pronouns??

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm not sure I fully understand the question.

Comment: I have hopefully clarified the question and suggest that it NOT be closed.

Comment: I do not understand. Where do people say «mei» instead of «meine» while keeping «mein»? I have never heard of that, but I know there are dialects that use «mi» for both, or others that use «mini» for «meine» and «mi» for «mein».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't about grammar but about creating a mingle of sounds hardly understandable.

There is no rule but flattening all vowels sticking out, omitting the *-e*, *du* and shortning -en and even *ein* to *'n* is typical. Often parts of compound words are skipped when they can be guessed from context.

> Ich brauche ein neues Auto. – Hast du schon einmal über einen Gebrauchtwagen nachgedacht?
>
> 'ch brauchn'neus Auto. — Hast'schoma über'n Gebraucht'n nachj'dacht?

Comment: +1, but this is also a matter of dialect. "Nachj'dacht" sounds like Brandenburg or Berlin to me, and I assume someone from Bavaria will use different contractions.

Comment: Bavarian e.g.: "Host iban Brauchtn aa scho noochdocht?"

Comment: @Philipp there's the "icke" for "ich" missing for the Berlin dialect ;) :D

Comment: In Swiss German, the full form may be: «I bruuchen es nöüs Outo. – Hesch scho mal überne Pruuchtwage nachetänkt?» This might be shortened to «I bruuch’s nöüs Out’. – ’sch scho mal übern’ Pruuchtwag’ nach’tänkt?»